# Replace values of integer vector by matching to position index of values in character vector

Tags: r

I know this is going to be simple, but I haven't been able to work it out or find a solution by searching.

I have a matrix of integers with integer values from `1:n` (created by converting some factors to indices). I want to match those values to a vector of `n` colours, given in hex string values (generated using the `scales` package).

```
Y <- sample(1:7, 20, replace=TRUE)  # for example
classcols <- c("#F8766D", "#C49A00", "#53B400", "#00C094", "#00B6EB", "#A58AFF", 
"#FB61D7")
# manually replace:
Y[Y==1] <- classcols[1]
```

I am a bit slow on the uptake, and can't work out how to do this except manually as above. The reason may show how stupid I am:

```
plot(X, col=Y)  # X has same shape as Y. I want to control the colours a bit more.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as if you're just trying to do this:

```
classcols[Y]
#  [1] "#C49A00" "#53B400" "#00B6EB" "#FB61D7" "#C49A00" "#FB61D7" "#FB61D7" "#00B6EB"
#  [9] "#00B6EB" "#F8766D" "#C49A00" "#C49A00" "#00B6EB" "#53B400" "#A58AFF" "#00C094"
# [17] "#A58AFF" "#FB61D7" "#53B400" "#A58AFF"
```

Here, I've just used the values of "Y" to index the values in "classcols". You can, of course, reassign the output to another vector to use as required.

Comment: That's even more embarrassingly simple than I had imagined.

Comment: In an attempt to salvage some reputation from this episode, here's how I worked out how to 'add' an alpha value to the output: `paste(classcols[Y], "50", sep="")`.